# Why I got this error? - unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I don't know why I got this error :'((
It seems like I cannot use array append and new_velocity could not read the particle_position_vector. Is there any solution for my error?

```
import random as rd
import numpy as np

particle_position_vector = []

#to randomize 
for _ in range(n_particles):
    a3=rd.randint(0,1)
    a2=rd.randint(0,50)
    a1=100-a2-a3
    particle_position_vector.append([rd.randint(0,1), rd.randint(0,2), a2, a1, a3]) 


pbest_position = particle_position_vector
gbest_position = np.array([float('inf'), float('inf'), float('inf'), float('inf'), float('inf')])
velocity_vector = ([np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) for _ in range(n_particles)])

iteration = 0
while iteration < n_iterations:
    print("iteration : ", iteration)
    for i in range(n_particles):

        fitness_cadidate = fitness_function(particle_position_vector[i])
        print(particle_position_vector[i],' ', -(fitness_cadidate))


    for i in range(n_particles):
#to update new velocity and position
        new_velocity = (W*velocity_vector[i]) + (c1*rd.random()) * (pbest_position[i] - particle_position_vector[i]) + (c2*rd.random()) * (gbest_position-particle_position_vector[i])
        new_position = new_velocity + particle_position_vector[i]
        particle_position_vector[i] = new_position


    iteration = iteration + 1
```

Input:

```
Inform the number of iterations: 10
Inform the target error: 1e-6
Inform the number of particles: 10
```

Then, the code only run at iteration 0 and generate this error

```
iteration :  0
[0, 0, 35, 64, 1]   26.724501800000002
[0, 2, 16, 83, 1]   13.9079791
[1, 2, 4, 96, 0]   6.9655632
[1, 0, 28, 71, 1]   29.718418700000004
[1, 0, 11, 88, 1]   27.8742026
[0, 0, 9, 90, 1]   23.903936
[1, 1, 9, 91, 0]   12.8856497
[0, 0, 43, 56, 1]   27.592368200000003
[0, 2, 31, 68, 1]   15.5352286
[0, 1, 42, 58, 0]   12.7122986
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-57e52263d20a> in <module>
     59 
     60     for i in range(n_particles):
---> 61         new_velocity = (W*velocity_vector[i]) + (c1*rd.random()) * (pbest_position[i] - particle_position_vector[i]) + (c2*rd.random()) * (gbest_position-particle_position_vector[i])
     62         new_position = new_velocity + particle_position_vector[i]
     63         particle_position_vector[i] = new_position

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: This is the culprit: `new_velocity = ... (pbest_position[i] - particle_position_vector[i]) ..`. `pbest_position[i]` and `particle_position_vector[i]` are lists.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are subtracting a list from another list. Try following in your python command line:

```
>>> [1, 7] - [2, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

To subtract element-wise you can use the following:

```
[a - b for a, b in zip([1, 7], [2, 2])]
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

To be exact here is the error:

```
pbest_position[i] - particle_position_vector[i]
```

Now the reason why `pbest_position[i]` can be a list that you are appending a random list to it. `append()` will append a list to list. For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a.append([3,4])
>>> a
[1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

So instead of `append()`, use `+` to add elements to array as following:

```
>>> a = a + [3, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To be exact, use:

```
particle_position_vector = particle_position_vector + [rd.randint(0,1), rd.randint(0,2), a2, a1, a3]
```